# Visual Tree Helper makes listbox SelectionChanged fire twice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

**Visual tree code**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                if (child != null && child is T)
                {
                    yield return (T)child;
                }

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                {
                    yield return childOfChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**selectionChanged code**

```
 private void mylistBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (mylistBox.SelectedItem == null)
            return;
             foreach (Button tb in FindVisualChildren<Button>(mainListBox))
        {

           Debug.WriteLine(tb.Name);
        }

        }
```

**output**
Note it writes the name of the two button twice so it loops 4 times and it only has 2 buttons.
optionBtn
optionBtn2
optionBtn
optionBtn2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many items are there in `mainListBox` at runtime? It must be 2 and that's why it print the buttons names twice (2 times for each item in the list box). There is nothing wrong with `SelectionChanged` or VisualTreeHelper

Comment: But i specify the selectedIndex. It seems you are right but, why cant i just focus on the selectedIndex?

Comment: Note that the xaml at runtime will be different than what you see, specially in the case of a List control where specific elements are generated for each item in the list. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have a list of task and all i want to do is delete that index and display a message but the messsage keeps popping up. So if there are 5 items it pops up 5 times.

Comment: You don't need a loop. All you need to do is call Remove() and pass the selected item. myListBox.Remove(myListBox.SelectedItem); then display your message.

Comment: Okay Alaa Masoud, i'm gonna try your recommendation, thanks for the help.